# Regex \R doesn't work inside character class

Tags: php, regex

In PHP, the escape character `\R` which should match any newline sequence doesn't work inside a character class.

I recently learned about this special character on another answer here on stackoverflow and to be honest I haven't been able to find much online to document it's existence - nowhere on php.net is it mentioned except in a user comment.

Question(s):

- Why won't `\R` work inside a character class?
- Where is it documented?

**EXAMPLE 1:** (https://regex101.com/r/vA8xV3/3)

```
$a = "line1
      line2"

echo preg_replace('/\R/',' ',$a);
```

Returns (finds match, replace with single space):

```
line1 line2
```

**EXAMPLE 2:** (https://regex101.com/r/vA8xV3/2)

```
$a = "line1
      line2"

echo preg_replace('/[\R]/',' ',$a);
```

Returns (no match):

```
line1
line2
```

Comment: Are you sure that's valid? Only one comment mentions that as working. You would think the manual would mention if it was actually supported.

Comment: With which function are you trying to use it? PHP supports a few different regexp formats -- at least [PCRE](http://php.net/book.pcre) and [POSIX](http://php.net/ref.regex). Can you provide an example/snippet?

Comment: Yes it's valid.  It works fine when not in character class.  See here: https://regex101.com/r/vA8xV3/1

Comment: @billynoah why not use \n instead?

Comment: @LiamSorsby - this is not a question about how to match newlines.  The is a question about the proper use and explanation or `\R`

Comment: @billynoah Yes I was just editing the comment to say that I know it doesn't answer why it doesn't work but just a sugestion.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for suggestions on how to match newlines.  Please keep comments relevant to the question.

Comment: "\B, \R, and \X are not special inside a character class. Like  other unrecognized  escape  sequences, they  are  treated  as  the  literal characters  "B",  "R", and "X" by default" - PCRE docs - http://pcre.org/pcre.txt

Comment: +1 on the question, as I doubt many people are aware of this scenario, including me before I hunted down the relevant section of the PCRE docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [PCRE manual](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> ### Escape sequences in character classes
>
> All the sequences that define a single character value can be used
>   both inside and outside character classes. In addition, inside  a 
>   characterclass, `\b` is interpreted as the backspace character (hex 08).
>
> `\N`  is not allowed in a character class. ***`\B`, `\R`, and `\X` are not
>   special inside a character class. Like  other  unrecognized  escape 
>   sequences,they  are  treated  as  the  literal  characters  "B",  "R",
>   and "X" by default***, but cause an error if the `PCRE_EXTRA` option is set.
>   Outside  acharacter class, these sequences have different meanings.

(emphasis on relevant bit added by me)

Comment: Thanks for googling that for me :-)  Was unable to find this documentation.. although it doesn't explain why or the logic behind this it does definitively define the behaviour in question.

Comment: @billynoah I suspect it's because of the underlying implementation needed to test unicode characters (Exemple [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/38d79e9449ac3bfd51927183b975ab9c01cfde57/ext/pcre/pcrelib/pcre_compile.c#L9003) for php. This would turn in a large overhead if in a character class with many others when testing all combinations. (Again I suspect, authors of the reference only could answer)

Comment: Makes sense.  Interestingly, as Dariusz Cichowski points out below, `\v` is ok inside character class with seemingly same matches.  I think the world needs regex police... or at the very least a regex new world order.

Comment: The underlying cause/reason appears to be with whether any decision-making is required for the metacharacter…

Comment: …`\v` and `\R` may have similar results, but `\v` removes any vertical space (newlines, vertical tabs, formfeeds) while `\B` removes different varieties of newlines, specific to the control verb set for the expression. So `\v` has a predefined static set, while `\B` uses a dynamic set based on bsr setting. It looks like `\v` is generally faster and equivalent to `\B`, but not for Unicode newlines, so best not to fully rely on `\v` for scripts needing Unicode support (email parsing being the most real world example for apps not expecting users inputting CJK characters)

Answer (score 3):

This is correct behavior. \R only works **outside** character class.
(At least this is true in grep an many others)

For grep:

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html

PHP uses perl-like expressions, so see peardoc:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Misc

> Since \R can match a sequence of more than one character, it cannot be
>   put inside a bracketed character class; /[\R]/ is an error; use \v
>   instead

Comment: I don't see how this gets an upvote.  My question explicitly asks "Why won't \R work inside a character class?" and you answer "\R only works outside character class."  It's absurd.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer with something that at does contribute to the question.  I never knew about `\v` but it made me laugh that regex101.com describes `[\v]` (in a character class) as "\v matches the character v literally (case sensitive)".. which is wrong.  But then goes on to actually match the vertical whitespace contrary to it's own statement: https://regex101.com/r/wL4hT4/1

Answer (score 1):

As for the reason why `\R` is not allowed inside character class, while `\d`, `\s`, `\w`, ... are allowed inside character class, it is because `\R` can match `CR LF` sequence (`\r\n`), which consists of 2 code points. It is for the same reason that `\X` is disallowed inside character class, since it matches a grapheme cluster, which can contains multiple code points.

A character class is supposed to match only a single code point/code unit, which makes it a deterministic construct, in the sense that it does not require backtracking. Allowing a code point/code unit sequence to be matched by a character class causes the character class to have variable length, complicates the minimum length/maximum length analysis, which is used in several optimization. It also requires a modification to the matching semantic. For example, given `[\r\n\R]`, should it match `\r\n` in the string `"\r\n"`, or should it follow the declared order and match only `\r`? In case of failure, should we allow it to backtrack?

I'm not sure about PCRE's implementation. However, in Java, length analysis is used to optimize repetition construct (e.g. with repetition of fixed length construct, you don't have to store the amount of characters matched in each repetition for backtracking), optimize the case where the input string does not meet minimum length requirement, and determine whether the expression in look-behind is allowed or not.

Comment: Thank you for your insight into the reasoning behind this.  This is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for.  I wish I could accept two answers here but a meager upvote will have to do.  Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Think I understand your question,
Essentially a character class matches whats in between the `[]` explicitly, so in your case `[\R]` will match a `\` and a `R`.
For example in the string `balhblahRajndsf\` you will have matched the `\ and R`. Does this make sense?

http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm

See Brackets, Ranges and Negation in the above link

Comment: A backslash inside a character class is a special character and to match you would need to write `[\\]`, therefore, no you are not correct.

Comment: Here `[\R]` match a literal R

Comment: If your trying to match a line break isn't it a lower case \r? See this link http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: lower case `\r` matches carriage return.  uppercase `\R` matches both `\r` and `\n`

Comment: @billynoah keep calm, I was just pointing the error as you did, just giving the actual result to let the author correct it's answer or delete it.